# TikZ: Box alignment not inline - wrong anchoring?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, positioning, tikz-styles, scoping

I came across the problem of correctly aligning a set of boxes in the following TikZ example:

[image: Example]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.multipart, backgrounds, fit}

\tikzset{
  bluebox/.style={
    draw,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    fill=blue!50!white,
    align=center,
    inner sep=2ex
  },
  whitebox/.style={
    draw,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    fill=white,
    align=center,
    inner sep=2ex
  },
  item/.style={
    draw,
    inner sep=1ex,
    fill=white 
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]

    % Box 1
    \node[whitebox, label={\strut Labelpgq}] (Box1) {\rotatebox{90}{\footnotesize{Something}}};

    % Box 2
    \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, fill=white, right=of Box1, label=Options A] (OptionsA) {
        \nodepart{one} A
        \nodepart{two} B};

    \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, fill=white, below=of OptionsA, label=Options B] (OptionsB) {
        \nodepart{one} A
        \nodepart{two} B};

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node[bluebox, fit=(OptionsA) (OptionsB), label={\strut Labelg}] (Box2) {};
    \end{scope}

    \draw[dashed] (Box1) -- (Box2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the box labeled as "Labelg" appears shifted, because the first inner box is anchored as "right=of Box1". However, the alignment couldn't be applied to the respective `scope` box.

**How can I align the box correctly (in line)?, and potentially have two "Options A" boxes next to each other?**

Comment: I'm guessing you're the same person as Johnny Joe? I would say that it's not necessary to ask a new question, you could rather have edited https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409674/tikz-box-alignment-and-label-position to remove point 1.

Answer (score 0):

i move answer to [original op question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409674/tikz-box-alignment-and-label-position).